# TextField appears shrinked vertically

Tags: javafx-2

I have the following components in a `Grid` layout:

```
1. Label span=2 cols
2. Label | ComboBox
3. Label | ComboBox
4. Label | ComboBox
5. TextField span=2 cols
6. Button span=2 cols
7. Label span=2 cols
8. ListView span=2 cols
9. ComboBox | ComboBox
10.Button span=2 cols
```

The problem is with no. 5 `TextField`, if the height of the window is not large enough, the `TextField` is displayed as just a line instead of a text box and thus making it unreadable. Meanwhile the `ListView` (in 8.) displays 15 rows although it has only 2 values to display.

How can i make the `TextField` not shrink? The only thing that should be shrinking is the `ListView`.

Comment: Have you set the minimum size of the text field?

Comment: No I have not. How do I know what should be the min height (depending on the font size etc.) of the text component?

Comment: In the Layout tab in Scene Builder select the 'Min Width' box and type in a height.  Alternatively you could set USE_PREF_SIZE which uses the preferred height of the text field.

Comment: txt.setMinHeight( TextField.USE_PREF_SIZE ) worked. Thanks Andy!

Comment: No problem, I've added the comment as an answer, please accept if this was useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Layout tab in Scene Builder select the 'Min Width' box and type in a height. Alternatively you could set USE_PREF_SIZE which uses the preferred height of the text field.